# How to correctly store/retrieve UTF-8 Data into MS-SQL tables

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, odbc

i'm having big trouble storing extended characters from UTF-8 in MS-SQL Server Tables.

Every extended character stored in in ASCII-extended range (8-bit). i didn't find any way to store and not distort the information stored or losing extended character info data.

my current setup for the server is:

- IIS 7.5
- PHP 5.6.11 (x86_64 VC11 Fast-CGI)
- SQL Server Native Client for SQL Server 2008 R2 8 (Used via ODBC)

Why i'm not using SQL-Server driver Extension for PHP, simple, Microsoft don't have any available build version of that driver for 64-bit.

What i have tried so far:

- my Fields are Nvarchar, Nchar datatype.
- Used `utf8_decode()` to prepare the date for INSERT/UPDATE statements
- Used `utf8_encode()` when i retrieve the Data with the SELECTs
- Used `mb_convert_encoding($string,[new_encoding],'UTF-8');` Where new encoding was Windows-1252, UCS-2, ASCII. (in subtitution of utf8_decode)
- Used `iconv();` With encoding CP437.(in subtitution of utf8_decode)

no success in any case.

what i'm experimenting when data is stored, and you make a SELECT directly into the database the extended characters in strings are shown as garbage.

lets say:

i write `"ánimo"` and that word its stored  as `"Ã¡nimo"` when i retrieve from table to screen displays as `"Ã¡nimo"`

```
input ----> decode_utf8() ---> MS-SQL ----> encode_utf8()---> screen
```

any Ideas ???

Comment: What's the encoding of the input ?

Comment: convert input encoding to ucs-2 --> insert --> select ---> convert ucs-2 to display encoding. I used old MS SQL and don't remember it supporting utf-8, but it did support utf-16. Don't know about later version.

Comment: @frz3993 input its UTF-8 (html5 and JSON)

Comment: So, the conversion should be utf-8 to ucs-2 ---> insert-> MSSQL --> select --> convert ucs-2 to utf-8